# Reuse previous value in window function

Tags: mariadb, window-functions

Is it possible to use `LAG()` to get the previous value of the current column?

The computation I need to do is the following:

```
value(n) = (value(n-1) + 1) * column(n)
```

meaning I already have a column, and I want to create a new one by multiplying the column by the previous value of the new column I am creating + 1...

**First value would be 1.**

Something like:

```
SELECT (LAG(col1) OVER (ORDER BY date) + 1) * col2 AS col1
```

The current cell value is defined by the previous value times another column.

If I try this I get undefined column col1 (of course since I am creating it in my query...)

In Excel it is extremely easily done with the following formula:

```
B2 = (B1 + 1) * A2
```

So, if the table has:

```
  date     | col2
------------------
2018-12-01 |  2
2018-12-02 |  3
2018-12-03 |  1
2018-12-04 |  4
2018-12-05 |  1.5
```

the result should be:

```
  date     | col2  | col1 
-----------------------------
2018-12-01 |  2    |    1 
2018-12-02 |  3    |    6           (1+1) * 3
2018-12-03 |  1    |    7           (6+1) * 1
2018-12-04 |  4    |   32           (7+1) * 4
2018-12-05 |  1.5  |   49.5        (32+1) * 1.5
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: What this `+1` means?  Have a look at [MariaDB Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/) about window functions.

Comment: @McNets +1 is part of the computation I need to perform. I ll update the question to make it clear.

Comment: I suggest you add a sample of a table with a few rows and the wanted result.

Comment: So what's the value of that new column for the very first row? 0?

Comment: @Colin'tHart First value would be 1

Comment: @Colin'tHart thnx for edit. I put 0 because it wasn't clear before your question. (Could it be 0, 1, col2 or any other starting value)

Answer (score 4):

This likely needs a [recursive CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/with/), since you want the value of the column to depend on the value of the previous (calculated) value of the same column.
<sub>(Recursive CTEs are available in MariaDB since version 10.2.2)</sub>

I assume that `(date)` is unique, otherwise the result will be non-deterministic:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  t AS
  ( 
    SELECT
        date, col2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rn
    FROM 
        tableX
  ), 
  cte AS 
  ( 
    SELECT 
        date, col2, rn,
        CAST(1 AS DECIMAL(10,3)) AS col1     -- starting value
    FROM 
        t
    WHERE
        rn = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        t.date, t.col2, t.rn,
        (c.col1 + 1) * t.col2                -- calculate col1
    FROM 
        t JOIN cte AS c
        ON t.rn = c.rn + 1
   )
SELECT date, col2, col1
FROM cte ;
```

Tested at: **[dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f4220f500f3ceb1b10a66e5091e3fded)**